# Pivot выходит за пределы родителя XAML

Tags: xaml, разметка, windows-phone-8.1

В процессе разработки заметил неприятную особенность контрола `Pivot` на `Windows Phone 8.1`. Он начинается с самого верха экрана, в то время, как содержащий его `Grid` имеет некоторый отступ. На изображении `Grid` с красным фоном и `Pivot` с прозрачным синим. Больше в коде страницы ничего нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что данная страница подключается во фрейм внешней страницы, и отступающий `Pivot` загораживает собой элементы внешней страницы, ограничивая взаимодействие с ними. Пробовал обнулять отступы пивоту, но эффекта нет. Как можно его "ограничить" родительским гридом или фреймом внешней страницы?

**UPD**. Я понимаю что можно назначить пивоту отступ сверху, но я не уверен, что высота StatusBar на всех устройствах будет одинаковой. Хотелось бы "железно" пришить его к верху родительского элемента, либо обрезать выходящую за него часть.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил на мой взгляд странновато, но лучше ничего не придумалось. Я перенес перекрываемый торчащим из фрейма пивотом контент ниже фрейма в коде. Таким образом получилось нечто вроде

```
<Frame Grid.Row="2"/>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Теперь `StackPanel` находится как-бы слоем выше, чем фрейм, и события тапа по нему нормально отрабатывают.